# How to make an UI which displays search results like Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, material-design, android-cardview, ui-patterns

[image: Google Maps Search Result]

The search result view of Google Maps has the Material design's card-like look, but the cards themselves are like lists.

I want to implement a similar search page where as the user types in, the first card shows matching results from user's history, and the second card lists the results returned by Google Places API. For this I intend to put CardViews ([ref](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)) in LinearLayout (which is inside a vertical ScrollView).

However I am not sure how do I get the cards to look like these lists.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk The question you linked to is different. It asks for creating expandable lists using cards. Cards are in a list. In my case I want a list inside a card, or atleast it looks like that. I can add a LinearLayout inside card and add TextView but that is not going to give me the exact look and feel as in Google Maps. How do I get those dividers between the TextView. Is there any predefined style for that?

Comment: For the Cards List view, you may check out this here: http://javapapers.com/android/android-cards-list-view/